# After turning the device, when running DialogFragment error

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-dialogfragment

there is a fragment with FAB and ViewPager:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
    private static final String DATE_PICKER_FRAGMENT = "dpf";
    private FloatingActionButton FABAddDay;
    BottomAppBar mBottomAppBar;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    SampleFragmentPagerAdapter mSampleFragmentPagerAdapter;
    Fragment mDaysListFragment;
    DialogFragment mDatePickerFragment;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, container, false);
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mSampleFragmentPagerAdapter = new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getActivity());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mSampleFragmentPagerAdapter);
        mDaysListFragment = DaysListFragment.newInstance();
        mDatePickerFragment = DatePickerFragment.newInstance();
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FABAddDay = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mBottomAppBar = view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_app_bar);
        mBottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.settings: {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                    }
                    default:
                        return true;
                }

            }
        });
        FABAddDay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mDatePickerFragment.setTargetFragment(mDaysListFragment, DaysListFragment.REQUEST_DATE);
                mDatePickerFragment.show(mFragmentManager, DaysListFragment.DIALOG_DATE);

            }
        });
        return view;
    }




    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
        private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"List", "Calendar"};

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public androidx.fragment.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return mDaysListFragment;
                case 1:
                    return new CalendarFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return tabTitles[position];
        }
    }
}
```

One of the fragments in the ViewPager gets the result from the DatePickerFragment (Dialog) and process it in onActivityResult, everything works fine, but if you rotate the device and then try to run the DatePickerFragment, an error occurs:

```
 Process: com.example.taskplanner, PID: 7851
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment DatePickerFragment{4d9dc48 (a5fb8e8f-12c0-4f7b-ad26-220f6322d846) dialogDate} declared target fragment DaysListFragment{990eae1 (70133c60-029f-4b23-ad5a-954b0abb630f)} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:805)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, what can I do?

Comment: Tried changing getFragmentManager to get ChildFragmentManager. The problem has not disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand why this error is obtained, it seems to be due to the re-creation of the target fragment. I tried to save this fragment and everything worked.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {

    mFragmentManager.putFragment(outState, "dlf", mDaysListFragment);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

onCreateView:

```
    if (savedInstanceState!=null){
        mDaysListFragment=  mFragmentManager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "dlf");
    }
    else
    mDaysListFragment = DaysListFragment.newInstance();
```